# Is there a way in which we can merge two meshes in edit mode?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, selection-tools, looping

I have two mesh islands in the same plane which overlap as shown in fig1.
[image] Now when I go to selection and do "select boundary loop", it selects the full boundaries of both the islands as shown in fig2 [image]. But what I ideally want to select is just the outermost loop of both the meshes combined as shown [image]. For this I wanted to merge both the islands as one island. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: you need to use the TinyCAD addon and its XALL option

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to really make it only "one object"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51318/how-to-really-make-it-only-one-object)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Select one of your squares. Apply a BOOLEAN modifier with UNION.
Make sure the subdivision number is the same, try aligning them vertex to vertex. Use snap if necessary.
Set the boolean operator to UNION and select the second square.
Voilá.
Thank you for your consideration to vote me as the answer by clicking to the left :the icon with a check mark and upvote this answer.

BFCT_Schiller

Comment: I don't want to match them vertex to vertex. Then it won't serve my purpose. And using boolean is same as hitting ctrl+j in object mode in my case.