# How to merge 2 parts of the same object?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

i have a simple question for you, i need to "merge" 2 parts of the same object in edit mode where the faces collide, here a simple example to better explain the desiderata:
[image]

IS it possible in Blender with a simple operation? or do i have to recreate the whole parts to make them collide correctly?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51318/how-to-really-make-it-only-one-object https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/how-can-i-add-vertices-to-intersection-of-two-edges https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28574/simple-way-to-creating-vertices-at-intersecting-planes-and-deleting-leftover-int/28577#28577

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Recorded a quick video showing how to easily do it.](https://youtu.be/Bzl77jzcMwg)

The steps are:

- Create two loop-cuts on the smallest/thinnest part.
- Snap the new loops along the X axis(or whatever axis are appropriate for your mesh) to the mesh you want to merge it with.
- Select the faces your mesh is going through and create an inset face.
- Scale down the new faces and snap the edges into the thin piece.
- When all edges/vertices are overlapping use Alt+M and select "By Distance" to merge overlapping vertices.
- Finish off by either manually selecting and deleting the interior faces or use Select - Select all by trait - Interior faces to select them and delete

Comment: Thank you, this is a good solution, but consider that my image is composed by only 1 object.

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple topology, just add there a few more edges and merge the vertices. You can use voxel remesh as that is just one click operation but it makes the next modeling impossible in a classic way.